block symbol appearing and disappearing
I installed Linux Ubuntu today, and this block symbol keeps flashing, appearing and disappearing all the time. I couldn't find any tutorial on how to fix it (note: I've installed several Linux distributions and they all have the same problem).
My machine is a Lenovo
i3 6006U
4GB RAM
HDD
